# Wrong background on custom input["text"] CSS

Tags: css, input, background-color

I'm trying to style a form `input["text"]` field, but I'm getting this **white border / background** all around, and I don't know how to get rid of it.

Can anyone help me?

[image]

```
.my-form-login input[type="text"] {
    background-image: url('../images/text-input.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    outline: none;
    width: 180px;
    height: 30px;
    border: none;
    padding: 5px;
}
```

Comment: Is this only happening on Chrome?

Comment: try setting background color to transparent

Comment: Try using `border-radius` from CSS3 if all you want is rounded corners.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A combination of border:0px + setting the background color solved it

Althought would be great to set it to transparent...

Thanks everyone.

```
.my-form-login input[type="text"] {
    background-image: url('../images/text-input.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    outline: none;
    width: 180px;
    height: 30px;
    padding: 0px;
    background-color: #444;
    border: 0px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `background-color:[background color of parent tag];`

Comment: The element that's showing the white background is almost definitely the `input` - it has a default background color of white. Just setting the background color to transparent will do for the most part.

Comment: thnx BoldClock and yes that input tag, need to set background color for input tag.